# Having trouble filtering out data from columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter

```
 Sheet 1                 Sheet 2
     A          B            A        

    oranges    12            oranges    
    peaches    8             apples      
    apples     7             
    bananas    5

Output
   12
    7
```

**=filter(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A:A)**

I know I was able to do this before but something not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(Sheet1!B:B,xmatch(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A))
```

Comment: Yep that was it. I  think before I was just doing a single match like

Comment: =filter(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!a1)